# Best way to select multiple MySQLi Entrys and output them one by one (Reloading the Page)

Tags: php, mysqli

So for a project I need to get all Rows where time() is between a defined Start and End-Time. Now I will show all details from one record. After a defined value (x Seconds) the next Record will be shown. This should be done using header("Location: ...");

What's the best way to check which was the last record shown, and which one should be shown afterwards?

Comment: Do you absolutely have to do it with header? It makes things a little more awkward. I would do a fetchAll, get the results into javascript, and loop through them replacing the content of a div with the current row. Is this approach a posibility or must you use header?

Comment: @AndrewB I don't really have to do it using header, but I don't know,... I always tried to use as much server-side actions as possible to avoid security concerns. Also because of the people who blocked JavaScript.

Comment: You can ensure safety by ensuring they can only request data you would like them to have. For instance, you get all your rows with the query that you make sure is safe, json_encode the result and print it. Then you can use jQuery's $.post and JSON.parse(...) to get the data from that page. Now you know they can only ever get the data you want them to have anyway.

Comment: Note you will probably have to use javascript to wait a number of seconds and call the next row's data anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you must use header, one approach could be to store the result of a fetchAll query in a session variable e.g. $_SESSION['allRows'] = fetchAll(...)

You could then use header and a $_GET variable to signal which index to show:

```
header("Location: page.php?displayRow=" . $_GET['displayRow']+1);
```

Assuming displayRow was defined for the current page.

Then to get the data just use     `$_SESSION['allRows'][$_GET['displayRow']]`